# Facebook login - OAuthException - #100

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, authentication, oauth

I am trying to solve a problem with FB authentication but getting #100 exception saying:

(OAuthException - #100) Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

Here is my initial login url:
https :// www. facebook .com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyurl.com%2FAccount%2FExternalLoginCallback%3FReturnUrl%3D%2F%26_*provider*_%3Dfacebook%26_*sid*_%3Dfc41017afc3f45438d4eff62be0d1a0e&client_id=304995946295983

FB response to it with:
http :// myurl .com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?ReturnUrl=%2F&**provider**=facebook&**sid**=fc41017afc3f45438d4eff62be0d1a0e&code=AQCfw_IsQLwBs8naiAa_bZAPQeO4FCVq26S0RePUIkBuJo6H1hJoz-pil3F-bJ3LkpsV83nAInUKpUluhcaT1FLF69GYhZfnYrFErAC65VBjaSPIw025yOL4dPWxF8evXCzf3DSEn41rynmKYGE7NHpkLu8CyWl9yXBMIMhiUOMGo51z28ZToJ-oxeKUe_ODoT7fz06kPhz3MbdTD_CkchoQ_NshS2WZDrKpE8jrGWSPO7Z48jko59U7F5qDMXbUNM7bnONqbfV8iZ5ii6pWgdSKPfQqT9j3CPAplCNsedrEnb5UTLRr08t3FPKIIFbkwLE#*=*

What am i doing wrong? Why it throws an exception? Url`s look to be same...
Please help!

Comment: Which redirect_uri have you set in the application configuration?

Comment: wht do u mean in application configuration?

Comment: In FB app i have App Domains with myurl.com and Mobile Site URL set to myurl.com